# Registry option "do not use proxy server for local addresses"

Tags: group-policy, windows-registry

I just create a gpo to configure proxy with this registry options:

https://theitbros.com/config-internet-explorer-11-proxy-settings-gpo/

HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]:

ProxyEnable (REG_DWORD) = 00000001;

ProxyServer (REG_SZ) = ipproxy:port

ProxyOverride (REG_SZ) = local url etc.

I would also need enable the image option.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaPMw.png)

How can i do it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

In the name "**ProxyOverride**" after entering all your addresses and at the end also enter `<local>` with both major and minor signs preceded by the sign ; used as a separator between one address and another, in this way you will see that the check will be activated on the box "Don't use the proxy server for local (intranet) addresses". If you don't want this box to be checked, avoid entering the value `<local>` in your addresses. If you want to leave the address field blank and have only the box checked, enter only the value `<local>`. I hope I have been helpful